# Alternatives to NTP for time synchronization

Tags: time, standards, ntp

As far as I understand, NTPv4 does not support timestamps beyond the 2036 year. While I am convinced that this issue will be addressed in the upcoming NTPv5 standard, I wonder if there are any alternatives to NTP that have already fixed it and provide timestamps in the 64-bit data format? Is NTP still relevant for time synchronization, or maybe it is an obsolete standard that should be changed with something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is somewhat incorrect.  NTP (v3 and v4) uses the concept of eras, ~136 years long (the one we are in started in 1900).  The closest era is chosen, as long as the offset is within 68 years (34 for some OSs), all is well:
"Returning to the interpretation of timestamps as fixed-point numbers, note that the integer portion represents an era of 136 years. This suggests the following general rule.

Let the system clock be set within 68 years of the correct time, even if the correct time is not known exactly. Then, the offset can be correctly computed by the on-wire protocol and used to adjust the system clock to the correct time relative to an external source.

As a practical example, consider an NTP client started somewhere in 2012. In principle, the system clock can be initially set any time between after 1944 in era 0 and before 2080 in era 1. However, since an era is 136 years, 1944 in era 0 corresponds to timestamp year 44, while 2080 in era 1 also corresponds to timestamp year 44. To avoid possible ambiguity, the time should be initially set within a more narrow range than 68 years, perhaps 50 years. In such cases, the NTP on-wire protocol and clock discipline will eventauly align the system clock to the correct time in 2012."
--from the official NTP docs at [https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/time.html](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Emills/time.html)